# "App size" growing over time even with app real size remaining basically the same

Tags: android, size

When looking at an app's used storage space, we can see 'App size', 'User data' and 'Cache'.

Regarding 'App size', I think it should increase in size only if and when an app update with a bigger size comes out. Because an app update entirely replaces the old app version.

However I'm in a situation where my app is, and has always been, very light (1.7MB of APK, and 3.5MB of 'App size' when just installed on a device), but on some devices where the app has been installed for quite some time, 'App size' has grown to, like, 14MB, even up to 80MB sometimes I've heard.

So, if you do a new install of the app, it takes only 3/4MB of space, like it should be.
But for some people who have had the app for some time (and have updated it to the same most recent version), 'App size' appears way bigger like I said above.

What exactly gets counted in the 'App size' then? I can't understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading any data and saving it locally? That's probably the reason.

So basically any database caching, image caching or any other resources that you download off of the internet.
You probably are choosing to download those things in the app specific space. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more info about where to persist your data.

Other option is you can choose to do your caching in external storage, but of course you need to consider the *sensitivity* of the data. External storage means easier access.

Comment: I use internal storage. But the size of these files can be seen in 'User Data'. I save 3MB, and User Data becomes 3MB. I remove them and save 15MB, and User Data becomes 15MB. App Size never changes immediately.

Some users have played for months, and still have App Size at 3MB. Others for the same time, and their App Size is bigger.